# CSV import rounds data to be imported in column DECIMAL(30, 20)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, decimal

I am trying to import data from csv to my table.
There are multiple columns having data type `DECIMAL(30, 20)`.
Data in `csv` seems correct but when imported it gets `rounded` off `randomly`.
Eg: data to be imported `0.0010602476772075` gets rounded to `0.00106024800000000000`

Comment: Consider `DOUBLE` instead of `DECIMAL(30,20)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was uploading the excel where in the data was formatted as general. I converted the data formatting to number and changed its precision to 20 in the excel file itself and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought of mine

You can use that column as string later you can convert it to decimal

Comment: @YashSanghvi if it works then please for Appreciation OF SO please upvote and answer accept

Comment: @YashSanghvi you accept your answer by giving thanks to me :P

Comment: Yes because @ZaynulAbadinTuhin your answer is a workaround to the mentioned problem.
The correct way to solve the mentioned problem should be what I've answered.
No hard feelings friend.

Comment: @YashSanghvi if it helps then its is SO appreciation that to give upvote and answer accepting btw thanks to you :)